# ¿Cómo podría optimizar este código de la mejor manera?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

El que hay dentro del `Try`:

```
public FactoryMessage<Estimacion> UpdateEstimate(Estimacion model)
    {
        using (var dbContext = new NXSContext())
        {
            using (var dbContextTransaction = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    dbContext.Estimacion.Attach(model);
                    var entry = dbContext.Entry(model);
                    var estimate = dbContext.Estimacion.Find(model.IdEstimacion);
                    if (model.HorasIniciales > 0)
                    {
                        entry.Property(h => h.HorasIniciales).IsModified = true;
                        model.TotalHoras = model.HorasIniciales + estimate.HorasControlCambio;
                        entry.Property(h => h.TotalHoras).IsModified = true;
                    }
                    else if (model.HorasControlCambio > 0)
                    {
                        entry.Property(h => h.HorasControlCambio).IsModified = true;
                        model.TotalHoras = estimate.HorasIniciales + model.HorasControlCambio;
                        entry.Property(h => h.TotalHoras).IsModified = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
                    }


                    dbContext.SaveChanges();
                    dbContextTransaction.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
                    throw;
                }
                messageEstimateCreate = messageEstimateCreate.AssignResult(messageEstimateCreate, model);
            }
        }
        return messageEstimateCreate;
    }
```

Comment: Depende de tu concepto de optimizar, si te refieres a tiempos tal vez convenga el uso de threads y métodos asíncronos, desde otro punto de vista podrías implementar Funciones cortas para disminuir el anidado

Comment: Podrías dar un ejemplo de cómo quedaría, según tu perspectiva me gustaría conocer y saber cómo lo harías tú para yo aplicarlo ya que no tengo mucho conocimiento de buenas prácticas

Comment: Que es lo que quieres optimizar? que problema tiene tu codigo? como puedes hacer un rollback si tu error ocurre antes de que se genere la transaccion?

Comment: Este comentario no tiene la intención de ayudarte directamente con esta pregunta, pero podría servirte para futuros proyectos.
Te recomiendo evitar usar Frameworks, librerías u ORMs, para el desarrollo de aplicaciones; fue lo que aprendí luego de más de 5 años en este rubro...

Revisa el canal del profesor Luis Dueñas, y encontrarás bastante información útil sobre temas de performance y buenas prácticas en desarrollo con .NET.

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCRlg1y4Rxp3IAQ2uMDxGq-A

¡Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

mira si a lo que te refieres es a las líneas de código o a la complejidad ciclomática, para optimizar el código lo primero que debes hacer es estandarizar, por ejemplo tu tienes la siguiente líneas:

```
model.TotalHoras = model.HorasIniciales + estimate.HorasControlCambio;
model.TotalHoras = estimate.HorasIniciales + model.HorasControlCambio;
```

debido a que están alterando la misma variable deberías ver si la formula para alterar las horas totales es la misma, en cuyo caso podría extraerse todo el código de la siguiente forma por ejemplo:

```
public FactoryMessage<Estimacion> UpdateEstimate(Estimacion model)
{
    using (var dbContext = new NXSContext())
    {
        using (var dbContextTransaction = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                dbContext.Estimacion.Attach(model);
                var entry = dbContext.Entry(model);
                var estimate = dbContext.Estimacion.Find(model.IdEstimacion);
                var cambioHorasIniciales = model.HorasIniciales > 0;
                var cambioHorasControlCambio = model.HorasControlCambio > 0;                

                entry.Property(h => h.HorasIniciales).IsModified = cambioHorasIniciales;
                entry.Property(h => h.TotalHoras).IsModified = cambioHorasIniciales;
                entry.Property(h => h.HorasControlCambio).IsModified = cambioHorasControlCambio;
                entry.Property(h => h.TotalHoras).IsModified = cambioHorasControlCambio;

                model.TotalHoras = model.HorasIniciales + estimate.HorasControlCambio; //se asume que se puede estandarizar

                if(!cambioHorasIniciales&&!cambioHorasIniciales)
                {
                    entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
                }

                dbContext.SaveChanges();
                dbContextTransaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
            messageEstimateCreate = messageEstimateCreate.AssignResult(messageEstimateCreate, model);
        }
    }
    return messageEstimateCreate;
}
```

en este caso lo que se reduce son las líneas de código, sin embargo la complejidad ciclomática se mantendría, por otro lado te sugiero crear un proyecto de pruebas de integración para que así puedas realizar estos cambios sin miedo de alterar negativamente la funcionalidad.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer, (y en mi humilde opinión), su código está bien (no veo algo que sea "optimizable" que haga la gran diferencia), lo que si me hace ruido es el bloque Catch.

Digo esto porque, ya que tienes un Catch y dentro del mismo generas un Rollback de la transacción, generas una nueva excepción. Cosa que está totalmente desaconsejado ya que no haces nada con él Exception que has Atrapado y encima generas uno nuevo.

**UPDATE:**

Recién revisando y viendo el comentario (pero viendo que todavía no puedo comentar) caigo en la cuenta de que tu código no sería válido, debido a que de la nada, estas retornando un valor que no declaras en ningun lado y tu funcion que mencionas devuelve un Objeto del Tipo FactoryMessage. Adicionalmente a lo mencionado, movería el valor que se pretende retornar al bloque try o en su defecto, adicionaría un bloque Finally (luego del bloque Catch).

Finalmente, haria algo con el bloque Catch(Exception) con algun tipo de Interfaz de Logger, algo en pseudocodigo tal como.

```
...
catch (Exception ex)
{
 dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
// ILogger vendría de algún lado o estaría accesible de alguna manera..
 ILogger.Log("Ha ocurrido un excepcion......", ex);
}
...
```

Comment: Si, de echo solo lo tenía para concepto de prueba, para analizar un error que tenía, pero en optimización y refactorización de código que me aconsejarías, sabiendo y aplicando las buenas prácticas de desarrollo ?